# Splunk: How to extract field directly in Search command using regular expressions?

Tags: extract, splunk, splunk-query

I have some log files which looks like this one:

*2020-11-18 00:11:22.333  INFO [ABC_service,[{"method":"doSomething","id":"123456789","jsonrpc":"2.0","params":{"taskType":"certainType","clientNotificationInfo":{"priority":xy,"expirationDate":111111111},"priority":xy,"deviceId":"000000000000000","taskPayload":{},"timeout":22222222}}, XYZ]*

I now would like to extract fields directly in my search and make a table of the extracted values. I would like to extract the taskType, here: *certainType*. Now, I was wondering about how to do this.

I tried this command:

```
source="/log/ABCDE/ABCDE_service.log" doSomething | rex field=_raw "taskType: (?<taskType>.*)"    | table  taskType
```

But got an empty table. What is wrong here?

But I got an empty table for both values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, but the regular expression in the `rex` command does not match the sample data.  Try this.

```
source="/log/ABCDE/ABCDE_service.log" doSomething 
| rex field=_raw "taskType\\\":\\\"(?<taskType>[^\\\"]+)"    
| table  taskType
```

The extra backslashes are needed for the multiple layers of escaping needed to get the quotation marks into the regex processor.

BTW, I like to use regex101.com to test regular expressions.